# Structure of $U_n/U_{n+m}$ where $U_i=1+p^i\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am trying some exercises on a course about algebraic number theory and I am slightly confused about the question.

First we are told to show that $U_n/U_{n+m}\cong\mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z}$ where $U_i=1+p^i\mathbb{Z}_p$ for sufficiently large $n$.

The second part asks us to "use this to prove that if $p$ is odd, $(\mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic. "

Edit: This is the actual question as it is stated.

> Let $U_r=1+p^r\mathbb{Z}_p$. Show that for $r$ sufficiently large, $U_r/U_{r+m}\cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Use this to prove that if $p$ is odd then $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic.

My attempt:
The first part I was able to show an isomorphism but only an isomorphism of groups.

As a set $U_n/U_{n+m}=\{1+ap^n+p^{n+m}\mathbb{Z}:a\in\{1,2,...,p^m\}\}$

Take $x=1+ap^n+p^{n+m}\mathbb{Z}_p$

$y=1+bp^n+p^{n+m}\mathbb{Z}_p$
Then, $xy=1+(a+b)p^n+p^{2n}(a+b)+p^{n+m}\mathbb{Z}_p$

So if we take $n\geqslant m$ , we get $xy=1+(a+b)p^n+p^{n+m}\mathbb{Z}_p$

And we have an isomorphism (of groups)

$U_n/U_{n+m}\to \mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z}$ given  by
$1+ap^n+p^{n+m}\mathbb{Z}_p\mapsto \bar{a}$

Hence, I am slightly confused the second part as $U_n/U_{n+m}$ has no multiplicative structure so as to speak and thus I cannot the isomorphism in (i). How do I endow the multiplicative structure on $U_n/U_{n+m}$?

(I would also appreciate if someone could tell me if there is a way to do this more abstractly such as using the isomorphism theorem for a particular mapping. Also, no where in the question have I used anything p-adic. Can I just not replace $U_i$ with $1+p^i\mathbb{Z}$ and still get the same thing?)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $1+p^i\Bbb Z_p$? Is it a subset of what? (I guess of the $p$-adic integers $\Bbb Z_p$) What structure does it carry? (I guess, it's a group under multiplication) How do you mean $U_n/U_{n+m}$ here?

Comment: Yes, subset of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as you say. (Both a coset and also a open subset w.r.t the p-adic absolute value.) And, yes I can endow $U_n/U_{n+m}$ with a group structure but not a ring structure?

Comment: Nobody came out and said it explicitly, but those things are being dealt with as groups with just the one law of composition, namely multiplication. The set $1+p^i\Bbb Z_p$ has no ring structure. So, for instance, if you show that $U_n/U_{n+m}$ is cyclic of order $p^m$, you’ve done all that has been asked for.

Comment: That is what I thought. So how does the first part help us to deduce that $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a cyclic group. (How does the first part tell us anything about the multiplicative structure of this ring?)

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking, but, except for embarrassments at $p=2$, it should be saying that in $\Bbb Z_p^\times$, the subgroup $1+p\Bbb Z_p$ is topologically generated by the single element $1+p$. That is, the infinite (multiplicative) cyclic group $\langle1+p\rangle$ has for its closure all of $1+p\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: I have added the actual question as it is stated in the edit above. The question is not about the structure of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ but the multiplicative group of units in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. However, as mentioned the isomorphism is a group isomorphism as $U_r/U_{r+m}$ does not have a ring structure